# linear programming minimum problem

Tags: linear-programming, nonlinear-optimization, integer-programming, operations-research

A construction company has 6 projects, for each they need $d_i$ workers. The company has no workers at the beginning of project 1.

Each new worker must take a safety course that costs 300, and 50 more for each worker.
If there is no new worker there is no course.

Firing a worker does not cost any money, and a workers can't be rehired.

Given that the salary of a worker is 100 per project, formulate a linear programming problem that minimizes the workers costs.

What I tried:

Let $x_i$ be the number of new workers for project $i$.

Let $y_i$ be the number of old workers remaining from previous projects until project $i$ (all the workers hired - all the workers that were fired)

Let $z_i$ be an indicator such that $z_i =0 \iff x_i>0$

The function I'm trying to solve is:

$\min(\sum_{i=1}^6 150x_i + 300(1-z_i) + 100y_i)$

s.t:
\begin{align}
x_i,y_i,z_i &\ge 0 \\
z_i &\ge 1-x_i \\
y_i + x_i &\ge d_i \\
y_i &\ge y_{i-1} + x_i
\end{align}

Something feels not right to me. The main reason is that I tried to use matlab to solve this and it failed.

What did I do wrong? How can I solve this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems correct except that the last constraint should instead be $y_i \le y_{i-1} + x_{i-1}$.